# Copying jar file into custom directory from target directory in maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I want to place the jar into `src/main/resources` directory and name this archive as `suffixingApp.jar`.

I went through many documentation and StackOverflow, but it seems, I may have messed up my source code (pom.xml) and Suffixing class.

When I run `AppTest.java`, it is returning:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/suffixing.jar (No such file or directory)

at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
    at com.epam.rd.autotasks.suffixing.AppTest.setup(AppTest.java:41)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

### Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.epam.rd.autotasks</groupId>
    <artifactId>suffixingApp-app-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <junit5.version>5.6.2</junit5.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-installed</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                    <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <outputDirectory>src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### Here is incomplete `SuffixingApp.java`:

```
package com.sarvar;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SuffixingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String rootPath = "src/main/resources/";
        String appConfigPath = rootPath + "app.properties";

        Properties appProps = new Properties();
        appProps.load(new FileInputStream(appConfigPath));
        String inputMode = appProps.getProperty("mode");
        String inputSuffix = appProps.getProperty("suffix");
        String inputFiles = appProps.getProperty("files");

        if (!inputMode.equalsIgnoreCase("copy") ||
                !inputMode.equalsIgnoreCase("move")) {
            Logger.getLogger("Mode is not recognized: " + inputMode);

            return;
        }

        if (inputSuffix.isEmpty()) {
            Logger.getLogger("No suffix is configured");

            return;
        }

        if (inputFiles.isEmpty()) {
            Logger.getLogger("No files are configured to be copied/moved");
        }








//        Suffixing suffixing = new Suffixing();
//
//        try {
//            System.out.println("Enter the name of file to rename");
//            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
//            String fileName = bufferedReader.readLine();
//            suffixing.setOldFileName(fileName);
//
//            System.out.println("Enter the suffix to rename the file's name");
//            BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
//            String suffix = bufferedReader2.readLine();
//            suffixing.setSuffix(suffix);
//
//            String newFileName = suffixing.getOldFileName() + suffixing.getSuffix();
//            suffixing.setNewFileName(newFileName);
//
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            throw new IOException();
//        }
//
//        try {
//            suffixing.walkDirectory(suffixing.getPath());
//        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
    }

}
```

### Lastly, here is `AppTest.java` if required:

```
package com.epam.rd.autotasks.suffixing;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.jar.JarInputStream;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;
import java.util.logging.StreamHandler;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

class AppTest {

    private static Method mainMethod;
    private static Logger appLogger;

    private ByteArrayOutputStream logSink;
    private StreamHandler appLogHandler;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException {
        JarInputStream jarStream = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/suffixing.jar"));
        Manifest mf = jarStream.getManifest();
        String mainClassName = mf.getMainAttributes().getValue("Main-Class");
        Class<?> mainClass = Class.forName(mainClassName);
        mainMethod = mainClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);

        appLogger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("");
        appLogger.setLevel(Level.ALL);

        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("src/test/resources/sandbox/config"));
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("src/test/resources/sandbox/cases"));

        FileUtils.copyDirectory(
                new File("src/test/resources/reference/config"),
                new File("src/test/resources/sandbox/config"));
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(
                new File("src/test/resources/reference/cases"),
                new File("src/test/resources/sandbox/cases"));

    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setupLoggerHandler() {
        logSink = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        appLogHandler = new StreamHandler(logSink, new SimpleFormatter());
        appLogger.addHandler(appLogHandler);
    }

    @Test
    void testAbsentFile() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        final String output = runApp("src/test/resources/sandbox/config/absent-file-config.properties");
        assertThat(output, containsString("SEVERE: No such file: src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/no-such-file.txt"));
    }

    @Test
    void testBadMode1() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        final String output = runApp("src/test/resources/sandbox/config/bad-mode-config-1.properties");
        assertThat(output, containsString("SEVERE: Mode is not recognized: CPY"));
    }

    @Test
    void testBadMode2() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        final String output = runApp("src/test/resources/sandbox/config/bad-mode-config-2.properties");
        assertThat(output, containsString("SEVERE: Mode is not recognized: DELETE"));
    }

    @Test
    void testCopy() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {
        final String output = runApp("src/test/resources/sandbox/config/copy-config.properties");
        assertFileIsCopied(output,
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/copy/copy.txt",
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/copy/copy.copy.txt");
    }

    @Test
    void testLowercaseMode() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {
        final String output = runApp("src/test/resources/sandbox/config/lowercase-mode-config.properties");
        assertFileIsCopied(output,
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/lowercase-mode/lower.txt",
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/lowercase-mode/lower-old.txt");
    }

    @Test
    void testMixcaseMode() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        final String output = runApp("src/test/resources/sandbox/config/mixcase-mode-config.properties");
        assertFileIsMoved(output,
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/mixcase-mode/to-move.txt",
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/mixcase-mode/to-move.mv.txt");
    }

    @Test
    void testMove() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        final String output = runApp("src/test/resources/sandbox/config/move-config.properties");
        assertFileIsMoved(output,
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/move/origin.txt",
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/move/origin.moved.txt");
    }

    @Test
    void testNoSuffixMove() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        final String output = runApp("src/test/resources/sandbox/config/no-suffix-config.properties");
        assertThat(output, containsString("SEVERE: No suffix is configured"));
    }

    @Test
    void testEmptyFiles() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        final String configFile = "src/test/resources/sandbox/config/empty-files-config.properties";
        final String output = runApp(configFile);
        assertThat(output, containsString("WARNING: No files are configured to be copied/moved"));
    }

    @Test
    void testThreeFiles() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {
        final String configFile = "src/test/resources/sandbox/config/three-files-config.properties";
        final String output = runApp(configFile);
        assertFileIsCopied(output,
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/three-files/1.txt",
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/three-files/1.old.txt");
        assertFileIsCopied(output,
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/three-files/2.txt",
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/three-files/2.old.txt");
        assertFileIsCopied(output,
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/three-files/3.txt",
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/three-files/3.old.txt");
    }

    @Test
    void testThreeFilesMiddleAbsent() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {
        final String configFile = "src/test/resources/sandbox/config/three-files-middle-absent-config.properties";
        final String output = runApp(configFile);
        assertFileIsCopied(output,
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/three-files-middle-absent/1.txt",
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/three-files-middle-absent/1.old.txt");
        assertFileIsCopied(output,
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/three-files-middle-absent/3.txt",
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/three-files-middle-absent/3.old.txt");
        assertThat(output, containsString("SEVERE: No such file: src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/three-files-middle-absent/2.txt"));
    }

    @Test
    void testTwoFiles() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {
        final String configFile = "src/test/resources/sandbox/config/two-files-config.properties";
        final String output = runApp(configFile);
        assertFileIsCopied(output,
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/two-files/1.txt",
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/two-files/1.old.txt");
        assertFileIsCopied(output,
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/two-files/2.txt",
                "src/test/resources/sandbox/cases/two-files/2.old.txt");
    }

    @Test
    void testNoFiles() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        final String configFile = "src/test/resources/sandbox/config/no-files-config.properties";
        final String output = runApp(configFile);
        assertThat(output, containsString("WARNING: No files are configured to be copied/moved"));
    }

    private void assertFileIsCopied(final String output, final String sourceFile, final String copiedFile) throws IOException {
        final Path sourcePath = Paths.get(sourceFile);
        final Path copiedPath = Paths.get(copiedFile);

        assertThat(output, containsString("INFO: " + sourceFile + " -> " + copiedFile));
        assertTrue(Files.exists(sourcePath), "File " + sourceFile + "must exist");
        assertTrue(Files.exists(copiedPath), "File " + copiedFile + "must exist");

        assertEquals(Files.readString(sourcePath), Files.readString(copiedPath));
    }

    private void assertFileIsMoved(final String output, final String sourceFile, final String copiedFile) {
        assertThat(output, containsString("INFO: " + sourceFile + " => " + copiedFile));
        assertFalse(Files.exists(Paths.get(sourceFile)), "File " + sourceFile + "must not exist");
        assertTrue(Files.exists(Paths.get(copiedFile)), "File " + copiedFile + "must exist");
    }

    private String runApp(final String configFilePath) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        mainMethod.invoke(null, (Object) new String[]{configFilePath});
        appLogHandler.flush();
        return logSink.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: A file embedded in a jar should be accessed as a resource, not as a file.

Comment: Note that `src/main/resources` contains _ressource_ files as per the name of the directory. By default Maven puts those resources into the root of the target jar's classpath so `String rootPath = "src/main/resources/"` would only ever work if the application is run from within the IDE. What does `suffixing.jar` contain? Why is that a resource?

Comment: There is test `JarInputStream jarStream = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/suffixing.jar"));` inside `AppTest.java`. Therefore, I expected that I shall just copy suffixing.jar file at least at the beginning. So, how can I accomplish it, I assume, I need to update my pom.xml file

Comment: What is the underlying problem you try to solve with this?

Comment: I solving the assignment given in course. It requires me "[Once you have designed it, place the jar into src/main/resources directory.](https://gitlab.com/khalimovsarvar/suffixing-app#comsarvarsuffixingapp-app:~:text=Once%20you%20have%20designed%20it%2C%20place%20the%20jar%20into%20src/main/resources%20directory.)"